# Fastest way of updating or alternatively inserting documents in MongoDB 4.2

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, bulkinsert, insert-update, upsert

Assume a MongoDB collection containing documents which must be updated with new fields or subobjects regularly; alternatively, if the document does not exist yet, the regular document update process shall insert a new document (a typical upsert).

What is the **fastest** way of achieving this? At the moment I have a three stage process which is very slow:

Stage 1: find the documents which must be updated based on a list containing their customIDs (there exists an index on the customID field).

```
        db[myCollection].find({'customID': {'$in': myUpdateList}})
```

Stage 2: iterate over the documents in the cursor retrieved in Stage 1, enriching them with new fields and/or subobjects. Add the new documents which can not yet be updated since they are not yet in the database to the same document list.

Stage 3: upsert to MongoDB using an Unordered Bulk Operation.

```
        bulk_mapping = db[myCollection].initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
        for key, value in enrichedDocs.items():
            bulk_mapping.find({'customID': key}).upsert().update({'$set': {'customID': key, 'enrichedBody': value['enrichedBody']}})
        bulk_mapping.execute()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to first `.find()` and then `.update()`, you can directly do `update` with `upsert` option.

Try this :

```
bulk_mapping = db[myCollection].initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
for key, value in enrichedDocs.items():
    bulk_mapping.update({
        'customID': key
    },{
        '$set': {
            'customID': key, 
            'enrichedBody': value['enrichedBody']
        }
    },upsert=True)
bulk_mapping.execute()
```

**Update**

you can use the below code with pymongo to achieve bulk update:

```
from pymongo import UpdateOne

bulk_operations=[]
for key, value in enrichedDocs.items():
    bulk_operations.append(
        UpdateOne({
            'customID': key
        },{
            '$set': {
                'customID': key, 
                'enrichedBody': value['enrichedBody']
            }
        },upsert=True)
    )

db[myCollection].bulk_write(bulk_operations);
```

Comment: thank you! Apart from that, are there any other improvements or other ways of doing it?

Comment: Other than this, i think you will have to one by one in a for loop, which is not such a good method to do it.

Comment: It produces an error: AttributeError: 'BulkOperationBuilder' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: The upsert argument shall not be passed as a dictionary in PyMongo, but as an option: please correct your answer to reflect this. Otherwise, your proposed approach seems to be 13% faster than the one described in my question. After you correct the answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: I updated my answer. Thanks for correcting me. I havent used pymongo much